# Using SQL's CASE for a large number of conditions?

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want to do is this:

```
case_1  case_2  case_3  Final
0           0    0      0
0           0    1      3
0           1    0      2
1           0    0      1
1           1    0      2
1           0    1      3
0           1    1      3
1           1    1      3
```

That means when case_1 is 0, case_2 is 0 and case_3 is 0, the final col has value 0.
    Similarly, when case_1 is 1, case_2 is 1 and case_3 is 1, the final cols will be 3.
    And so forth.

And what I ended up typing in SQL which is awkward:

```
Select *,
case when case_1>0 and case_2>0 and case_3>0 then 3 else 0,
case when case_1>0 and case_2>0 and case_3=0 then 2 else 0,  
case when case_1>0 and case_2=0 and case_3=0 then 1 else 0,
....
....
....
from mytable;
```

Now this is seriously bad, I know that. Can there be better way of such coding?

Comment: Can those columns hold anything other than `0` and `1`?

Comment: @Barmar No. only 0, 1, 2 and 3 for Final column and rest three have either 0 or 1

Comment: I don't really understand. Why does your desired output only have one `Final` column, but your query has multiple `case` expressions? Which one of those is the real `Final`?

Comment: So when case_1 is 1 and case_2 is 1 and case_3 is one, the Final col will have result as 3.

Comment: But which column gets the value from `case when case_1>0 and case_2>0 and case_3=0 then 2 else 0,`?

Comment: Maybe these should all be part of one big `CASE` expression, not separate ones?

Comment: Based on your sample output, the expression you would need is - `CASE WHEN case_3 > 0 THEN 3 WHEN Case_2 > 0 THEN 2 WHEN Case_1 > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`. Which, in my opinion, is not over complicated or unmanageable.

Comment: @GarethD Looks like you've decoded it, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: @GarethD No. I think you did not understand. `Case_1>0 and Case_2>0 and Case_3>0 then outputh in final column will be 3 (which is digit of case_3) and if case_1=0 and case>2 and case_3=0 then the result for the this will be 2 and so forth (as shown in the first table)`

Comment: @MadhuSareen His solution works: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/144b1/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the example, it looks like the priority is case 3 -> case 2 -> case 1. In which case, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN case_3 > 0 THEN 3
     WHEN case_2 > 0 THEN 2
     WHEN case_1 > 0 THEN 1
ELSE 0 END AS `Final`
FROM table;
```

Comment: Fix your `CASE` syntax. You don't repeat `CASE` before each `WHEN` clause.

Comment: @Barmar cheers for the heads up. It was a copy paste error :(

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want the rightmost position of nonzero column, if any

```
 select *,
    case when case_3>0 then 3 else 
      case when case_2>0 then 2 else
       case when case_1>0 then 1 else 0 end
      end
    end final
 from tbl
```

Comment: You don't need to nest multiple `case` expressions, you can use multiple `WHEN` clauses in a single expression.

Comment: @Barmar  right, `case when.. when  end` will do. Let me leave my answer as is just to show full long version.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, electrical engineering knows this problem as "generating a Boolean expression from a truth table."

I'm going a different direction from the other answerers.

Create yourself a tiny lookup table with eight rows and four columns, like this

```
SELECT * FROM final

| case_1 | case_2 | case_3 | Final |
|--------|--------|--------|-------|
|      0 |      0 |      0 |     0 |
|      0 |      0 |      1 |     3 |
|      0 |      1 |      0 |     2 |
|      1 |      0 |      0 |     1 |
|      1 |      1 |      0 |     2 |
|      1 |      0 |      1 |     3 |
|      0 |      1 |      1 |     3 |
|      1 |      1 |      1 |     3 |
```

Then join to it to your main data table to do your lookup of the `final` value, like this (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4de009/1/0).

```
  SELECT a.Name, b.Final
    FROM test a
    JOIN final b ON a.case_1 = b.case_1 
                AND a.case_2 = b.case_2
                AND a.case_3 = b.case_3
```

Performance? Not a problem on an eight-row lookup table. SQL is made for this.

Flexibility? If your rules for computing `Final` change all you have to do is update the table. You don't have to do the Boolean expression simplification again.

Complexity?  Well, yes, it's more complex than a nested bunch of CASE or IF statements. But it's easier to read.